# How can I access a class inside a project from build.gradle.kts?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a project with several classes, one of the classes has a method that generates a json file and returns it, and I want to call this method in build during the build of the project.gradle.kts, generate a json file and put it in the resources of the finished jar file.

I've already done a task that generates a resource, but I can't access classes from the project.
I attach the task code, I checked on it that the resource file is basically generated:

```
tasks.register("generateFile") {
    doFirst() {
        val resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.get().output.resourcesDir
        resourcesDir!!.mkdirs()

        val contents = "project=$project.name"
        File(resourcesDir, "project.properties").writeText(contents)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use classes from the *project you are building* inside the *build script that is building them*? That's never going to work.